findstr recursive search but exclude all the folders starting with . in one line
I want to make a recursive search with findstr while excluding folders starting with . (e.g. .git\, .github\, .ipynb_checkpoints\, etc.).
Based on this answer, I am using
findstr /C:"valid" /N /S *py | findstr /V ".*\\"

but returns files in .ipynb_checkpoints\ folder. I would like to have a one-line solution.

The findstr /V ".*\\" part is not working because the backslashes seem to be treated in a weird way. Part of the problem is caused by cmd.exe (in PowerShell, it's a bit different). Using four backslashes (in cmd.exe) will match a single backslash in the input, and it nearly works:
findstr /C:"valid" /N /S *py | findstr /V ".*\\\\"

Unfortunately, the above will not only omit .ipynb_checkpoints\* but it will also omit lines where the dot is not at the beginning of the line - even if you use /B.
The following works, using regular expressions:
findstr /C:"valid" /N /S *py | findstr /V /R "^\..*\\\\"

If you use PowerShell, use just two instead of four backslashes:
findstr /C:"valid" /N /S *py | findstr /V /R "^\..*\\"


It didn't work: https://imgur.com/a/1uJr6zC

@Barzi2001 I didn't know you were using PowerShell. I had tested it with cmd.exe. Also, I missed out a backslash in my answer (now corrected). It should start with "^\.. Could you please try it in cmd.exe?

@Barzi2001 I've now tested it in PowerShell. You need to use just two backslashes there (see my edited answer).
